# Can't reach file by php script

Tags: php, file

Today i wanted to create some php script which will force download mp3 files directly.

File i want to download is placed in sounds folder and i can access to it via http://playall.pl/sounds/ThemadpixprojectBadChick.mp3

But when it comes to php script - function file_exists says, that this file is not on this server.

How can i fix it?

Code im using to download file

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

And to get filename and file url

```
$file_name = ''.$sound['Sounds']['artist'].' - '.$sound['Sounds']['title'].'.mp3';

$file_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $file_name);

$file = 'http://playall.pl'.$this->webroot.'sounds/'.$sound['Sounds']['src_url'];
```

Comment: Why don't you just redirect the browser?

Comment: Because i want to force download this file on button click.

Comment: And to add, im using CakePHP framework.

Comment: `file_exists` checks filesystem, not the internet

Comment: So, when im using CakePHP, and file is in app/webroot/sounds/ how url to file song.mp3 placed in that folder would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `file_exists($file)` the variable `$file` needs the full path. And has to be a path on the filesystem, not a url for web location.

So you need something like:

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/webroot/sounds/';
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the filesystem path to your htdocs folder, so the rest needs to be relative from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem was very simple - i had a / in front of path. Now its working correctly. Thanks all for help!